# Why no "division by zero" error in PostgreSQL for such case?

Tags: postgresql

Noticed the following behavior of PostgreSQL 9.5:

Division of something by zero - works as expected:

```
# select 1 / 0;
ERROR:  division by zero
```

Dividing `NULL` by zero:

```
# select NULL / 0;
 ?column?
----------

(1 row)
```

I browsed the documentation, but didn't find any reference to the reasons for such a design decision. The result of the dividend can depend on data - can be something or `NULL`, so the result - `NULL` or error - will depend on data. Wouldn't that be safer to throw error in all cases when divisor is known to be zero?

Comment: Any mathematical operation with NULL as one of the operators will return NULL

Comment: @eurotrash, my question is more about the design decision: why rule "return NULL if any operand is NULL" is stronger than "throw error if attempt to divide by zero"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more about SQL Standard than anything:

> An arithmetic operation involving a NULL returns NULL. For example,
>   NULL minus NULL yields NULL, not zero.

The decision in this case is just to follow SQL ANSI.